# Quartz schedulers in two different clusters for the same application are firing at same time

Tags: java

i am using Quartz scheduler to pushing automatic emails daily specific time. My application was configured in two clusters. Schedulers in both the clusters are firing at same time and sending duplicate emails to users. Please suggest me the code to make sure that only one scheduler will fire.
I have done googling and found that JDBC-JobStore will resolve the issue.But i dont want to store schedule informaltion in db. Will RAMJobStore will resolve the issue? below is my existng code.

```
      <bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetails" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 51 10 * * ?"/>
</bean>
 <bean id="jobDetails"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="sendEmails" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="executeJob" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>
<bean id="sendEmails" class="com.westin.agi.PushNotification"></bean>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the code.

Comment: Do you think that both clusters have access to the same RAM?

Answer (score 2):

Usually the RAM of each server is separated, so the behaviour that both cluster members have their scheduler fire at the same time is expected.
If you do not want to use a database for synchronization, you can use a memory grid solution like Hazelcast.
Actually there is a project to achieve exactly your use case with Hazelcast and Quartz:
https://github.com/mufumbo/quartz-hazelcast